# Regex and SftpStreamingInboundChannelAdapterSpec

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp

We tried to use Sftp inbound stream adapter to ingest data in our mongo database.

We receive file according pattern SRMTparty_create_20191010033028.csv on sftp server.

When I configure a regex or simple file pattern filter, they are never found.

If I put the complete filename it's ok.

To exclude regex problem, I tried it with Pattern in simple hello world class.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(SRMTparty_create_)(.*)(\\.csv)");
String s = "SRMTparty_create_20191010033028.csv";
Matcher match = p.matcher(s);
System.out.println(match.find());
```

it's ok.

My code is below :

```java
    @Bean(name = "sftpInboundPartyAdapter")
    public SftpStreamingInboundChannelAdapterSpec sftpInboundAdapter() {
        return Sftp.inboundStreamingAdapter(remoteFileTemplate)
                   .remoteDirectory(sftpRemoteDirectory)
                   .patternFilter(sftpRemoteFileName)
                   .maxFetchSize(1);
    }
```

I hope somebody can help me !

Have a nice day.

Comment: You need to show the code including setting `sftpRemoteFileName`. The filter uses `matcher.matches()` not `matcher.find()` - the whole name must match.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to investigate more what is an `AntPathMatcher` - an approach used behind that `SftpSimplePatternFileListFilter`:

```
 * <p>Part of this mapping code has been kindly borrowed from <a href="https://ant.apache.org">Apache Ant</a>.
 *
 * <p>The mapping matches URLs using the following rules:<br>
 * <ul>
 * <li>{@code ?} matches one character</li>
 * <li>{@code *} matches zero or more characters</li>
 * <li>{@code **} matches zero or more <em>directories</em> in a path</li>
 * <li>{@code {spring:[a-z]+}} matches the regexp {@code [a-z]+} as a path variable named "spring"</li>
 * </ul>
```